# How to apply border-radius on select2 boxes?

Tags: html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4, jquery-select2

I have a default bootstrap user select box, where I apply a `border-radius` style:

```
<div class="container">
  <select class="form-control" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
    <option value="1">User 1</option>

    <option value="2">User 2</option>

    <option value="3">User 3</option>

    <option value="4">User 4</option>

    <option value="5">User 5</option>

  </select>
</div>
```

So, I decided to update this select to use the jQuery lib [select2](https://select2.org/) to get the searching feature, but I lost the border-radius formatting.

```
<div class="container">
  <select class="form-control js-example-basic-single" style="border-radius: 1rem;">
    <option value="1">User 1</option>

    <option value="2">User 2</option>

    <option value="3">User 3</option>

    <option value="4">User 4</option>

    <option value="5">User 5</option>

  </select>
</div> 


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.js-example-basic-single').select2();
});
```

There is any way to apply border-radius when I use select2 in my select boxes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Select2 append another element after the original select so if you want to style it, you can target it with `.select2-container .select2-selection`. For more specific, if you want to style only select2 of `.js-example-basic-single`, the selector will be `.js-example-basic-single + .select2-container .select2-selection`.

[Working Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/zht57gwm/5/)

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks